# JQuery Datatables Confirm delete row

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am having trouble adding in a delete confirmation on my JQuery datatable. I have a on click method on my delete button which calls the confirmation script which works but, if I click cancel, the row gets deleted when it should only be deleted if "Ok" is clicked.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var assetListVM;

            $(function () {

                assetListVM = {
                    dt: null,

                    init: function () {

                        dt = $('#file_list').DataTable({
                            "serverSide": true,
                            "processing": true,
                            "ajax": {
                                "url": "@Url.Action("GetFiles","AttachmentsUser")",
                                "data": function (d) {
                                    d.s = $('input[type=search]').val();
                                }
                            },
                            "columns": [
                                { "title": "FileName", "data": "file_name", "searchable": true },
                                {
                                    "title": "Actions",
                                    "data": "file_name",
                                    "searchable": false,
                                    "sortable": false,
                                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                        return '<a href="@Url.Action("Download","AttachmentsUser")?file=' + data + '" class="download">Download</a> | <a href="@Url.Action("Delete","AttachmentsUser")?file=' + data + '" class="delete"  onclick="DeleteFunction()">Delete</a>';
                                    }
                                }
                            ],

                        });
                    },

                    refresh: function () {
                        dt.ajax.reload();
                    }
                }

                $('body').on('keyup', 'input[type=search]', function () {
                    assetListVM.refresh();
                });
                // initialize the datatables
                assetListVM.init();
            });

        </script>
        <script>
            function DeleteFunction() {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user - have you removed all roles for this user?'))
                    return true;
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `return` to cancel default browser behavior.

```
onclick="return DeleteFunction()"
```